# OCaml satisfable logical operation

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a function in ocaml that gets a logical operation as a parameter(defined like this:)

```
type oper = B of bool 
            | V of string
            | Neg of oper
            | And of oper * oper 
            | Or of oper * oper
            | Impl of oper * oper
```

and returns "true" if the operation is satisfable (it returns true in at least one case) and "false" if it's not satisfable(it returns false in all cases). For this, I'm trying to substitute the V s with either B true or B false until I get true and raise the Do_it exception. If I don't get true in any cases, I'll throw the Not_found exception and evaluate what exception I get at the end of the program.

```
  let satisfable operation=
    let switch x var tf=
        let rec aux1 =function
          |B b->B b
          |V s when s=var ->aux1 (B tf)
          |V s->V s
          |And(e1,e2)->(match aux1 e1, aux1 e2 with
                       |(B false,_)|(_,B false)->B false
                       |(B true, x)|(x,B true)->aux1 x
                       |(x1,x2)->And(x1,x2))
          |Or(e1,e2)->(match aux1 e1,aux1 e2 with
                      |(B true, _)|(_,B true)->B true
                      |(B false, x)|(x,B false)->aux1 x
                      |(x1,x2)->Or(x1,x2))
          |Impl(e1,e2)->(match aux1 e1,aux1 e2 with
                    |(B false,_)->B false
                    |(B true,x)->aux1 x
                    |(x1,x2)->Impl(x1,x2))
          |Neg b->(match b with
                  |B b-> B (not b)
                  |s->Neg (aux1 s))
        in aux1 x    
    in let rec aux = function
         |B b->B b
         |V s->(match switch operation s true with
               |B true->raise Do_it
               |x-> aux (switch operation s true)
               )
         |V s->(match switch operation s false with
                |B true->raise Do_it
                |x-> aux (switch operation s false)
                )
         |V s->raise Not_found
          |And(e1,e2)->(match aux e1, aux e2 with
                       |(B false,_)|(_,B false)->B false
                       |(B true, x)|(x,B true)->aux x
                       |(x1,x2)->And(x1,x2))
          |Or(e1,e2)->(match aux e1,aux e2 with
                      |(B true, _)|(_,B true)->B true
                      |(B false, x)|(x,B false)->aux x
                      |(x1,x2)->Or(x1,x2))
          |Impl(e1,e2)->(match aux e1,aux e2 with
                    |(B false,_)->B false
                    |(B true,x)->aux x
                    |(x1,x2)->Impl(x1,x2))
          |Neg b->(match b with
                  |B b-> B (not b)
                  |s->Neg (aux s))
                     in if(try aux operation with Do_it->B true|Not_found->B false)=B false then false else true;;
```

But it does not work the way I want to, and in some cases it even throws a Stack overflow exception.

The function "switch" returns an operation in which the string variable "var" has been substituted with the value of tf(true/false)

Comment: You say it doesn't work the way you want to. What did you expect and what happens?

Comment: when I call it with
 satisfable (And (V"s",Neg(V "s")));;
it returns false because (s&&!s) can never be true. But when I call something that should be true in at least one case, it throws an exception(stack overflow)

Answer (score 2):

Your function `aux` is using an outer definition of `operation` that doesn't change with each recursive call.

Comment: I think that's voluntary, as there are no variable declarations.

Comment: If you keep passing the same thing in the recursive call, the recursion may not terminate. This is my worry. The other problems cited here will not cause infinite recursion, they'll just get the wrong answer, as far as I can see.

Comment: I didn't see it, you indeed need to update operation for every variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `aux`, you match three times on `V s`. Only the first case will be analyzed. Also, calling two times `switch operation s true` is not a good idea, you can avoid repeating two times the same calculation by declaring `let case_true = switch operation s true`.